# Display Activity Indicator while app is busy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, spinner, loading

I'm developing a Cross Platform mobile app with Xamarin.Forms.

I'm trying to simulate a POST on web service with a simple Activity Indicator and I button. I want that on button click the Activity Indicator displays and remains until IsLoading property is set to false.

Here my XAML:

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="layOuter">
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actWebRequest"
        IsVisible="{ Binding IsLoading,
                             Mode=TwoWay }"
        IsRunning="{ Binding IsLoading,
                             Mode=TwoWay }"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 100, 100"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />


    <Button x:Name="btnLogin"
                    IsVisible="{ Binding Show,
                             Mode=TwoWay }"
                    Text="{ StaticResource LoginButtonText }"
                    Command="{ Binding LoginCommand }"
                    BackgroundColor="Teal" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And he the LoginCommand:

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
            return;

        backingField = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private bool _isLoading;
    private bool _show;

    public bool IsLoading { get { return _isLoading; } set { SetValue(ref _isLoading, value); } }
    public bool Show { get { return _show; } set { SetValue(ref _show, value); } }

    private void Login()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        Show = false;

        // DoSomething()
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

        IsLoading = false;
        Show = true;
    }
```

By tapping the Login button nothing happens, and after 5 seconds the application navigates to another. I also tried ACR User Dialogs but it doesn't works.

My app must be Android and iOS compatible.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

EDIT:

Yes, I binded the page to WievModel in this way:

```
public class ContentBase<T> : ContentPage where T : class, new()
{
    public T ViewModel
    {
        get { return BindingContext as T; }
        set { BindingContext = value; }
    }

    public ContentBase() { ViewModel = new T(); }
}

public class LoginPageBase : ContentBase<LoginViewModel> { }

public partial class LoginPage : LoginPageBase
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isLoading;
    private bool _show;
    public bool IsLoading { get { return _isLoading; } set { SetValue(ref _isLoading, value); } }
    public bool Show { get { return _show; } set { SetValue(ref _show, value); } }
}
```

What I mean is that when I tap the Login button the Activity Indicator doesn't show even if I set IsLoading to true.

Comment: 'By tapping the Login button nothing happens, and after 5 seconds the application navigates to another.' - Please elaborate. Did you set the binding context of the page / view?

Comment: I added some other code. About the navigation; what I mean is that this page is Login page so in my real code, for the moment I commented the credential check procedure becouse I want only see the Activity Indicator, at the end of Login method I've `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())` so I tap the button, Activity Indicator doesn't show and after 5 seconds it navigates to HomePage.

Comment: Why is your binding for IsLoading TwoWay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is obvious:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
```

You are blocking the main thread with `Wait()`, await it instead:

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);
```

Then you should see the activity indicator.